# I need to stop a database process from happening after it occurs 10 times

Tags: c#, timer

This method adds something to db every 5 seconds.

I want to stop this process after 10 products added.

How can i stop this process?

```
public static  void AddMyProductToDB()
{
    Timer myTimer = new Timer(5000);
    myTimer.Start();
    if (!CountControl())
    {
        myTimer.Stop();
        myTimer.Enabled = false;
        myTimer.Dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(MyWork);
        while (true) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to run  MyWork Method every 5 seconds and want to stop it when CountControl Method is false ,it doesn't stop,continious to running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have infinite loop which will block the code from being executed for the second time.

Also you seems to have to read this tutorial

http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer

OR use this code snippet

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    MyWork();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```